# Can you get more pc boxes in pokemon y/x?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series

Can you get more pc boxes In pokemon x and y?

Comment: Well, how many do you have? Many boxes are unlocked by storing enough Pokemon in boxes... one box is specifically unlocked by catching your version specific legendary (as you are *required* to catch it, this ensures there's an open box for it.) If you've truly filled all available boxes, there's always the pokebank.

Comment: I only have 7 plus the battle box . I swear I've seen people with more

Comment: Put at least a Pokemon in each box you have, it will unlock onther boxes.